# Proper use of Pip in Python3.3's venv

Tags: python, python-3.3

Just trying to figure out the intended use of Python3.3's implementation of [PEP405](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/), which is the venv spec. This is my first dive into Python3, as I've been in Python2 up until now.

Running Linux Mint KDE, which is pretty much a Debian distro, I compiled and installed Python 3.3.2. To try out this fancy new feature, I went to where I wanted to create a venv, and ran `python3.3 -m venv testenv`. It properly created the env. What confuses me, according to the spec, there should be a pysetup3 file inside the bin directory, however there isn't such a file. My guess is that it's the equivalent to easy_install.

Since there is no standard install scripts inside the env, I just downloaded and ran the easy_install script, and then ran `easy_install pip` to get a pip command for my env.

Is this pysetup3 script an old idea that didn't make the cut? Am I supposed to reinstall easy_install and pip on each new venv?

Comment: Interesting. It's might be worth noting that the [current documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) makes no mention of the `pysetup3` script, but does mention (in the grey **Note:** box) having to do the `distribute_setup.py` dance after activating the `venv`.

Comment: I've tried using Python 3.3's `venv`, but after experiencing issues such as this I went back to using `virtualenv`.  I'm hoping that Python 3.4's [inclusion of `pip`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/) makes it much nicer to work with `venv` in the future.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, I wonder if that's the reason they didn't include a script to auto-install easy_install and pip then upon creation of a venv.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jim Garrison for pointing me in the direction. It seems [PEP453](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/) will solve the issue of what seems to be missing in new environments using `venv`. PEP453 states that `pip` will be available by default in Python installations, including the explicitly referenced `venv`. PEP453 is slated to be included in Python 3.4. I guess for now in Python 3.3, we'll have to manually install `setuptools` and `pip`, or continue to use `virtualenv`.

No idea what `pysetup3` is from [PEP405](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/), but I guess not everything has to be to spec. :)

Answer (score 2):

Until pip is a part of Python in 3.4, you can create virtual environments that include pip by running [this script](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#an-example-of-extending-envbuilder) available in the docs.  The script simply extends venv's EnvBuilder class to install setuptools and pip after creation of the environment.

Pip installs to the venv's "local/bin" folder.  You'll want to symlink it to the "bin" folder so that it works as expected after running "activate".  From the shell, type:

```
ln -s /path/to/venv/local/bin/pip /path/to/venv/bin/pip
```

Alternatively, you can add two lines of code to the install_pip() method in the [script](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#an-example-of-extending-envbuilder) to do this for you each time:

```
def install_pip(self, context):
    ... (default script code) ...
    # Add these two lines at the end:
    pip_path = os.path.join(context.env_dir, 'local', 'bin', 'pip')
    self.symlink_or_copy(pip_path, os.path.join(context.bin_path, 'pip'))
```